# How to Regex a string

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-alternation

Is it possible to check with regex:

1. the complete string are numbers **AND**
2. the first character is a 7 or 8 then the complete length of the string must be 11 **OR**
3. the first character is a 1 then the complete length of the string must be 10
4. **OR** the first character is a 0 then the complete length of the string
   must be 18 AND on character 8 must be a 8 or 7 OR on character 9
   must be a 1

I hope you can see what I mean. Hope the examples will help you to know what I mean.

Here is my solution(not working completely-> I don't know how to check if in case it starts with a 0 and it is 18 characters long the character on position 8 must be 7or8 or on position 9 the character must be 1):

```
^(?:[78]\d{10}|[1-69]\d{9}|[0]/d{18})$
```

For example:

- **8**5556987456 -> starts with 8 and length is 11 -> match
- **7**5556987456 -> starts with 7 and length is 11 -> match
- **1**555698745 -> starts with 1 and length is 10 -> match
- **0**000000**8**5556987456 -> starts with 0 and length is 18 and on pos 8 is a 8 -> match
- **0**000000**7**5556987456 -> starts with 0 and length is 18 and on pos 8 is a 7 -> match
- **0**0000000**1**556987456 -> starts with 0 and length is 18 and on pos 9 is a 1 -> match

Thank you!

Comment: Use: `^[78][0-9]{10}$`

Comment: Or: `^(?:[78]\d{10}|[1-69]\d{9})$`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I have forgotten one more condition. I've edited the original post

Comment: Then try give it your best shot with the samples given and include your own attempt. That may get your question reopened again.

Comment: I edit my post with my not complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[78]\d{10}|1\d{9}|0\d{6}(?:[87]\d|\d1)\d{9})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LVqCGF/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[78]\d{10}|1\d{9}|0\d{6}(?:[87]\d|\d1)\d{9})` - one of the three alternatives:

  - `[78]\d{10}` - `7` or `8` and then 10 digits (11 all in all)
  - `|` - or
  - `1\d{9}` - `1` and then 9 digits (10 all in all)
  - `|` - or
  - `0\d{6}(?:[87]\d|\d1)\d{9}` - `0`, then 6 digits, then the 8th digit equal to `8` or `7` and any one digit, or any one digit and the 9th digit equal to `1`, and then 9 more digits (=18 digits)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex:
/^[78]\d{10}$/

"^" indicates the start of the line
"$" indicates the end of the line
\d means digits
{10}means exactly 10
[] is a group of valid values

The second question is dependant on wether your Engine supports Lookahead and Lookbehind https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: I don't think you'd need lookarounds for this right. Just an alternation would do.